# nanoseconds cause date_time_parse_exception in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

we are using an elastic search service connector connected to kafka topics.

In some kafka topic messages the field `time` contains unix time in nanoseconds in the form `'1646302527.329244000'`. The ElasticSearch Service Sink Connector passes the message to ElasticSearch but apparently changes the representation from `'1646302527.329244000'` to `'1.646302527329244E9'`.

Which throws a `date_time_parse_exception` when trying to parse the value for the associated `date_nanos` field.

```
    [2022-03-03 10:15:27,705] ERROR Error encountered in task simple-elasticsearch-connector-0. Executing stage 'TASK_PUT' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask'. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient$ReportingException: Indexing failed: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [time] of type [date_nanos] in document with id 'indexName+1+2517991'. Preview of field's value: '1.646302527329244E9']]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=failed to parse date field [1.646302527329244E9] with format [strict_date_optional_time_nanos||epoch_millis]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=date_time_parse_exception, reason=date_time_parse_exception: Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers]]
```

Probably the error is caused by a wrong configuration of the converter of the connector. Does anyone know which converters are most useful for this scenario? Please note that the other messages in the `time` field use the ISO 8601 format `'2022-03-03T11:08:57+00:00'`.

#### Versions

- ElasticSearch 7.14
- ElasticSearch Service Sink Connector 11.1.8
- Kafka Confluent Community edition: 7.0.1, Scala 2.13
- Java 11

#### ElasticSearch Service Connector Configuration

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "localhost:8081",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics":  "topic1,topic2,topic3,topic3",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "connection.password": "password",
    "connection.username": "username",
    "key.ignore": true,
    "schema.ignore": true,
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "IGNORE",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": true
 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the error logs of the ElasticSearchConnector the error suggests that the scientific notation e.g. `'1.64630003428232E9'`

comes from the Kafka messages. Instead, the representation is generated by the Jackson parser during the mapping from ElasticSearch. In Kafka the value is originally represented as double `'164630.003428232'`.

The solution is an ingest pipeline that checks if the value is a double when indexing all messages, if yes the value is cast to integer to discard the comma part.

```
if (ctx['time'] instanceof Double){ ctx['time'] = (int)ctx['time']}
```

The id of the ingest pipeline was then entered in the index and index template settings

```
"index.default_pipeline": "transform_date"
```

Using the integer, ElasticSearch can parse the date format epoch time in seconds

Answer (score 0):

here is the proof of the previously only speculated cause

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double eventTime = 1645081544.728914000;
        SimpleDateFormat SDFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/ dd/ yy");
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("The unparsed" + " value is: " + eventTime);
            cal.setTime(SDFormat.parse(eventTime.toString()));
            System.out.println("Time parsed: "
                    + cal.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException except) {
            except.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

when you run the java code, the following exception occurs

```
The unparsed value is: 1.645081544728914E9
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1.645081544728914E9"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:31)

Process finished with exit code 0
```